# Querying dbpedia resources user input

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, sparql, dbpedia

In a program I'm writing in jquery, users search for youtube videos using a search bar. I return results with the /search resource, and among other things, I need to show additional information from DBpedia. For example, if a user searches for a song, I need to show information about that song, I guess using dbo:abstract. The endpoint I use is http://dbpedia.org/sparql. My question is, how can I query dbo:abstract with the sole knowledge that the rdfs:label of the resource I want depends on a variable returned by the youtube api(e.g. snippet.title)?

Comment: Then write a SPARQL query that checks for matching labels? Or what are you asking now? Indeed it will fail if the `rdfs:label` and your text don't match. Fuzzy matching isn't part of SPARQL indeed, this would require a text index like based on Lucene or similar tools.

Comment: Is there a way to check for matching between `rdfs:label` and my text with a SPARQL query? I'm not sure. Could you post an example?

Comment: Looking further into sparql queries, I think I could solve my problem with parameterized queries

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you just have to create a query string that uses the text as value of the triple pattern with the `rdfs:label` property, or not? (`?s rdfs:label "your_text"@en .`) It is just string replacement in the language of you choice, thus, Javascript. Or are you not sure how to create the SPARQL query at all? Indeed, if you have a good SPARQL API that supports parameterized queries, it is a good and clean way to use it.

Comment: As said before, don't forget that this would do exact match i.e. it would also be case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Your welcome. If you found a working solution for you, feel free to provide it here as an answer. Might help others having the same issue/question.